# CSS/HTML Percentage Advice

Tags: html, css, web

I have decided to move over to percentages rather than fixed pixels in the hope of minimizing the input for a fully responsive website, but have already encountered and error. I am on the nav bar, and when testing how it looks, the text just overflows off the screen like nothing at all is stopping it! I don't know why I have tried : Putting it in a wrapper, Setting a max width, changing padding, Margin:0 auto;

```
#nav{
width:100%;
height:10%;
position:fixed;
background:#ccc;
padding-left:10%;
padding-right:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it the problem could be your height attribute. I'm assuming the text is spilling down the screen, not off the side of it?

Having a set height is usually a bad idea, especially as percentage heights can be quite irritating to work with. For example, inline elements take their percentage widths and heights from whatever is inside them. If that's the word "hello" then it's 10% of however much of the screen that word would take up.

With responsive design it's usually best to use a percentage for your width and just set height to "auto", or on most browsers you can just not put it in your CSS as "auto" is the default value anyway.

However, for a quick fix that'll stop text spilling out of the box, "overflow:hidden" will hide anything that flows outside of the element.

Comment: Hello, setting this to auto didn't fix the problem! I appreciate the quick fix, but it's going to be used all the way down the website and would want it to wrap (going to be a one page site) so it's better to get it sorted now, thanks.

Comment: Can you put the file online somewhere so we could take a look?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/e8xULNQp It's on there, that is literally all that is there, i've just started it two mins before I posted this!

Comment: Assuming the issue is that your content is flowing out of the box then the removing the height part from #nav is the best way to go. I just tested it there and it worked. If it's a different issue, let us know though

Comment: Oh, never mind. I saw the issue on that site. The problem is that it's all one word and the browser is trying to fit it all on one line. "word-wrap:break-word" will cause it to move everything to the next line. text-align:justify would also work in a similar way

Comment: Just in case you didn't get a notification I edited my previous comment to offer a better solution

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!! Thank you so much for your help, it truly is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should use box-sizing:border-box, so the total width of the box (including borders, margin and paddings will be 100%).

```
#nav{
width:100%;
height:10%;
position:fixed;
background:#ccc;
padding-left:10%;
padding-right:10%;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

If you don't use the border-box box-sizing, then the total width of the box will become the specified width + padding + margin + borders.

Read about the box model here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Comment: This worked for only the background colour, but not the content :(.

Comment: [better link for `box-sizing` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). Friends don't let friends link to [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)